# Clarification of iterating through maps using for(auto iter : value)

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, maps

I know that in order to loop through a map in C++11 I can use the following code:

```
std::mymap<std::string, myclass>

for(auto item : mymap)
{
    // code here
}
```

What exactly is referred to by `item`?  Is it the map key?  The value that is currently accessed?  If I want to do something with the value, how do I access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Iter` refers to a `std::pair<std::string, myclass>` in your context. So `iter.first` is your key and `iter.second` is value  for your example.

If you want to modify value inside loop block, you can write as follows:

```
iter.second=<new value>
```

If you don't need to modify the value better to use your range loop as follows:

```
for(const auto& iter : mymap)
{
 //
}
```

Comment: Okay, I think this makes sense.  If I have a member function, I would just use `iter.second.myfunction();`, correct?

Comment: In your example context, if you have a function  like `myclass::myfunction()`,   you can call as `iter.second.myfunction()`

Comment: It's a `std::pair<const std::string, myclass>` actually.

Comment: What are the advantages of using `const`?  How is `&iter` different from `iter`?  Will I need to access `iter.first` and `iter.second` differently in the case of `&iter`?

Comment: @brandaemon if you are not making any changes in iterated elements, if you use `const`  code will be more clear with your intention. If you use reference instead value semantics, system don't need to create temporaries by copying the original elements.

Comment: `iter` (which is a pretty bad name, since it isn't an iterator) is a `std::pair<const std::string, myclass>`. Note the `const`.

Comment: @T.C. If it's not an iterator, what exactly is it?